# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

I have created a helper function which accepts a string array as input and the index of the column as selected output.

```
public static List<T> GetByIndex<T>(string[] data, int index)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (item.Contains("|"))
        {
            string[] s = item.Split("|");
            list.Add(s[index]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

At line `list.Add(s[index]);` i get the error `Cannot convert from 'string' to 'T'.`

How can i make this method generic?

The function should return string or integer or even maybe boolean

Comment: Why do you use generic `T` at all? You are working with `List<string>`: `public static List<string> GetByIndex(string[] data, int index)` etc. Just imagine that `T` something weird, say `Form`: what should be returned as a `List<Form>` then?

Comment: What `T` are you passing to the call. Say I pass `T` as some custom class `MyClass` what should happen? Why are you trying to make this generic in the first place?

Comment: It could accept string or integer

Comment: But if it would accept an integer why should this condition `item.Contains("|")` apply to an integer? or `string[] s = item.Split("|");` - your whole method accepts strings, handles strings and returns strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a `List<T>`, you need to provide some way of converting each string into a `T`.

Such as:

```
public static List<T> GetByIndex<T>(
    string[] data,
    int index,
    Func<string, T> convertItem)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (item.Contains("|"))
        {
            string[] s = item.Split("|");
            list.Add(convertItem(s[index]));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

And you could provide convenience overloads for the types you commonly use.

For example:

```
public static List<int> GetIntByIndex(string[] data, int index)
{
    return GetByIndex(data, index, int.Parse);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i make this method generic?

You shouldn't. You're only dealing with strings so make the method return a `List<string>`

```
public static List<string> GetByIndex(string[] data, int index)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if (item.Contains("|"))
        {
            string[] s = item.Split("|");
            list.Add(s[index]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

If you need to also support `int` then just make an overload which returns a `List<int>` and use `int.Parse` / `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't want generic `T` at all: what is the expected output for, say, `T == IComparer<DateTime>`?

I suggest getting rid of `T` and returning `List<string>`:

```
public static List<string> GetByIndex(string[] data, int index) {
  // Public method's arguments validation
  if (data is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
  if (index < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

  List<string> list = new List<string>();

  foreach (string item in data) {
    // Do not forget about nulls
    if (item != null) {
      // We can stop earlier on Split: 
      // if, say, index == 2 we don't want all 12345 items
      string[] s = item.Split('|', index + 2);

      // s can well be too short 
      if (s.Length > index)
        list.Add(s[index]); 
    }
  }

  return list;
}
```